# My computer turns off right after Windows Loads?

Tags: windows-7, crash, shutdown, safe-mode

I built a new computer about 2 months ago.  3 days ago the following problem started occuring -

When I turn on the computer and Windows loads, instead of letting
me put my password, it just turns off. The white light on the top of my PC is still
on but the monitor does not receive any signal and the PC basically appears turned off despite the light. Sometimes, I can put my password before it "turns off". Sometimes things will work for 5 minutes before the problem occurs.

I have tested 2 different monitors, and tested those monitors against other machines, so I know its not a monitor problem.

I already tried to Repair Windows (By pressing desperately F8 when the PC boots) and tried to load an old PC (I don't know hot to say that in english, I tried to make the PC one day
ago, like, load the files from one day ago). Also no solution.

Already tried to run on SafeMode, and it runs perfectly.

I Talked to a friend and he told me that he think I should do a back up and format the
Pc.

I'd like to know what people on this board think.  I also note that I'm running windows 7. I also have 2 coolers on my PC, so I don't think it is overheating the pieces.

Thank's for the help

Comment: Only a hint: If the Safe Mode runs fine it may be connected to installed software or drivers that run with the system in Normal Mode. You may either Uninstall recently installed drivers while in the Safe Mode or set [Clean Boot Mode with MSCONFIG tool](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/331796) in Safe Mode and then boot up in Clean Boot Mode to check the result. Clean Boot Mode switches off almost all non-generic processes that may run with Windows.

Answer (score 0):

It might have enough coolers but that means nothing without heat-sink paste. Make sure you have enough and *new* heat-sink paste between your CPU and the heat-sink on top of the CPU.

Comment: Overheating isn't likely the issue since the system runs fine in Safe Mode.